# Ruby: Parse Time String to accept in MySql as a valid date time

Tags: mysql, ruby

I am parsing set of xml records that has time stamp strings. My end goal is to parse these records and put them in mysql database. I am new to ruby and script was put together by looking at other examples in online:

Here is how my xml records looks like:

```
  <row Id="253828" UserId="56959" Name="Teacher" Date="2009-03-08T00:27:31.807" />
  <row Id="253829" UserId="22221" Name="Popular Question" Date="2009-03-08T00:32:32.217" />
```

This is how the ruby method looks like:

```
require 'date'

    @st = @my.prepare("insert into badge(id, user_id, name, created) values(?, ?, ?, ?)")
    if element == 'row'
      @st.execute(attributes['Id'], attributes['UserId'], attributes['Name'], DateTime.parse(attributes['Date']).strftime("%F %T"))
    end
```

But the problem is after parsing close to 10,000 something records I get a mysql error:

```
Incorrect datetime value: '2009-03-08 02:02:32' for column 'created' at row 1 (Mysql::Error)
```

I started to check this in repl and here is the out put of repl:

```
irb(main):016:0> DateTime.parse('2009-03-08T00:27:31.807').strftime("%F %T")
=> "2009-03-08 00:27:31"
irb(main):017:0> DateTime.parse('2009-03-08T00:32:32.217').strftime("%F %T")
=> "2009-03-08 00:32:32"
```

If you look carefully you see that orginal time string had `2009-03-08T00:27:31.807` and value `807` didn't make any impact on the conversion. Because if we change the two time strings to be exact except the different is the last three digits after `.` then I have a feeling the conversion is incorrect. I wonder whats the best way to convert this to valid mysql time stamp while keep the the integrity of the data.

Hypothetically, lets say time string is `2009-03-08T00:27:31.807` and `2009-03-08T00:27:31.507` the trying this on repl would give us:

```
irb(main):018:0> DateTime.parse('2009-03-08T00:27:31.807').strftime("%F %T")
=> "2009-03-08 00:27:31"
irb(main):019:0> DateTime.parse('2009-03-08T00:27:31.507').strftime("%F %T")
=> "2009-03-08 00:27:31"
```

They are both same time stamp but are they?

I found following post in StackExchange DataBase Admin section: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48704/mysql-5-6-datetime-incorrect-datetime-value-2013-08-25t1700000000-with-er not sure if I should do something like that.

To give a complete picture from the mysql side: Here is how my table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE badge
(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(40) NULL,
    created TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fractional-seconds.html

Comment: For representing the timestamp in Ruby, you also need to add `%N` to get the milliseconds. ```DateTime.parse('2009-03-08T00:27:31.807').strftime("%F %T.%N") => "2009-03-08 00:27:31.807000000"```

Comment: @CBroe wow thats a disaster because then any analysis I do on this data will not be accurate. What steps can I take?

Comment: @SeanRedmond Thanks, looks like now we are capturing it but as CBroe mentioned MySQL will drop this. I wonder what is the best practice on this. I bet I am not the first to see this issue :)

Comment: If you need that fractional seconds data, you will have to store it in a separate column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, the resolution of stored time information is one second.  The millisecond values you have shown (`.807`) etc, can't be stored. As far as your table is concerned, `2009-03-08T00:27:31.807` and `2009-03-08T00:27:31.507` happened at precisely the same second.

As of MySQL version 5.6.4, fractional time data can be stored if you define the column's data type correctly.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html

You may be able to succeed in this xml-to-MySQL conversion process by passing your [ISO 8601 timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) as text strings to the database, then doing your date/time conversion using a MySQL query with a form like this:

```
 INSERT INTO whatever
    ...
  VALUES 
     (..., 
      CAST(STR_TO_DATE( ? ,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%f') AS DATETIME),    
      ...)
```

I've tried this on a variety of server versions. It seems to be version-proof.

If you're using MySQL prior to 5.6.4, and you need to keep the milliseconds, you have a pain in the neck in your near future. You might consider storing your timestamps as UNIX style microseconds in a bigint. Your application code will need to use `strftime("%Q")` to get the microsecondy UNIX timestamps.

If any of your dates are before 1-Jan-1970, this won't work either.

Comment: Just edited the question to add the table create info. also how in ruby i do the insert. Do you think I should create the column differently?

Comment: so I should first get the unix time using `strftime("%Q")` and then use that time to insert to the database and then convert afterwards.

Comment: It's hard to be more specific about what you should do without knowing what you're trying to do. For many applications, one-second time resolution is plenty. It may not be for this application. But if you need millisecond time stamps, it helps to know why.

Comment: XML data files are data dumps and I creating a MySQL database to store them to do analytics works such as behavioral analysis. Mili-seconds are not that important in that case but i thought I ll use `strftime("%Q")` as you said to get the UNIXTIME and store it the database in that way i don't loose any information. And during analysis just convert from ruby or python or R to get year,month,date,time...